# Accessing data from model in Ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, variables, model

In my app Current user sets his general goal through a form in the `index.html.erb`

now I want to bind that value to a instance variable and display this instance variable in the view.

I'm rather new to ruby on rails so I'm not sure how to manage that.

I have tried various types of code to access the data with out any luck.
Can anyone help me with that?

for example:

```
@general_goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
general_goal = @general_goal.user.general_goal
```

gives the error: `Couldn't find Goal with 'id'=`
and

```
@general_goal = Goal.find(params[:general_goal])
```

also gives the error: `Couldn't find Goal with 'id'=`

this is the `goals_controller.rb`

```
class GoalsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_goal, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]
  #before_action :goal_owner, only: [ :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @goal = current_user.goals.build
  end

  def index
    @Newgeneralgoal = Goal.new

    @goals = current_user.goals.order(created_at: :desc).limit(5)   
  end

  def create 
    @goal = Goal.new(goal_params)
    @goal.user_id = current_user.id

    if (@goal.save)
      redirect_to transaction_path(current_user), :notice => "Goal has been saved successfully."
    else
      f.html { redirect_to "", notice: "Error: Goal Not created!!"}
    end 

  end

  def update
    if @goal.update(goal_params)
    flash[:success] = "Goal was successfully updated"
    redirect_to goals_path(@goal)
  else
    render 'edit'
  end       

  def destroy
    @goal.destroy
    flash[:danger] = "Goal was successfully destroyed"
    redirect_to goal_path(current_user) 
  end

  private

  def set_goal
    @goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
  end

  def goal_params
    params.require(:goal).permit(:user_id, :general_goal, :date)
  end
end
```

I can access the goal in the view with:

```
<% @goals.each do |goal| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= goal.date.try(:strftime,"%Y/%m/%d")%></td>                      
    <td><%= goal.general_goal  %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

so I am basically asking, if the user sets the general goal to maybe "5" how can I grab that "5" from the database and assign it to a variable?

here is the `schema.rb`for goals

```
create_table "goals", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "date"
  t.decimal  "general_goal"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
end
```

and here is the goal.rb model

```
class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

here is the user.rb model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

     has_many :goals

 end
```

Comment: any instance variable (starting with `@`) defined in the controller should be available in the corresponding view(s) and partial(s). So if your action `new` defines the `@general_goal`, then in your `new` view you should be able to access to `@general_goal` (it could be `nil` though).

Comment: I can access the @general_goal in the view with, `<h3>generalGoal</h3>
 <%= @general_goal %>`  and it is not empty since this is the out put from the console `#<Goal id: 6, date: "2017-08-16 00:00:00", general_goal: #<BigDecimal:7ff542eb67b8,'0.5E3',9(18)>, user_id: 3, created_at: "2017-08-16 15:29:55", updated_at: "2017-08-16 15:29:55">`

Comment: Then what are you trying to achieve? It is not clear what you are asking

Comment: sorry @MrYoshiji I've added more to the question, at the bottom

Comment: Its unclear what is `general_goal` by looking at `@general_goal.user.general_goal`. Is it an attribute in ``users table?

Comment: No it´s an attribute in the goal table

Comment: So you want to fetch a `general_goal` of a `goal` for a specific user? Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes, please see my edit, I added schema.rb and goal.rb. I am basically asking, if the user sets the general goal to maybe "5" how can I grab that "5" from the database and assign it to a variable?

Comment: As per your code, `<%= goal.general_goal  %>` should work. What it returns? Isn't it showing the correct value?

Comment: no its not working, not even if I do `<%= @goal.general_goal %> `or `<%= @goals.general_goal %> `   I can display the general_goal with the `each`loop... I wan´t to be able to assign the general_goal value to a instance variable such as @general_goal

Comment: maybe you should try to figure out how to get the data in rails console. It will look the same in the controller/view, except you pass data between the constants by assigning to instance variables.

Comment: Does your user model have `has_many :goals` relation defined in it?

Comment: @LauraPaakkinen Yes it has `has_many :goals`

Comment: I see 2 ways to access goals in the examples you have provided. In the beginning you have provided `user.general_goal` and later in the index action `current_user.goals` do both of them work?

Comment: nope neither of them works

Comment: Can you provide the user model? Can you also describe what is not working? Are you getting and empty relation? Or some kind of error message?

Comment: I edited the question @LauraPaakkinen, added user model and described the error messages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152085/discussion-between-laura-paakkinen-and-codegirl).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, You want to show the value of `:general_goal` for `current_user`?

This might do the trick for you, just put this code in the `index`in the controller. I haven't tested it, but it might work.

```
current_general_goal = @current_user.goals.sum(:general_goal)     
@general_goal =  current_general_goal.nil? ? 0 : current_general_goal
```

It checks if the :general_goal is nil, if so it displays 0, if not it displays the general goal value.

**update**

If you want the value from the last `general_goal`from the current user. You can add this code to your index view.

```
current_general_goal = @current_user.goals.last.general_goal
@general_goal =  (current_general_goal.nil? ? 0 : current_general_goal)
```

Please let me know if this works for you

Comment: Thank you @DaudiHell this code works, but it shows me the sum of all the `general_goal`, I changed the code to `current_general_goal = @current_user.goals(:general_goal).last   
      @general_goal =  (current_general_goal.nil? ? 0 : current_general_goal) `   but then it gives me this `#<Goal:0x007fd4734aa818>`in the view.... why is it not showing the last number instead of this `#<Goal:0x007fd4734aa818>`?

Comment: Ok I get it, you want the last `current_goal`from `current_user`. The way you changed the code it is showing the objects string in the output, I'll edit the answer.